# Drop-down in ASP is acting differently

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown in my aspx page from which I am downloading data.
From dropdown I will choose the file format and data will be downloaded in that particular format

Here is my drop-down.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExportRprts" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlExportRprts_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Excel" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="CSV" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and here is the back-end method of the dropdown.

```
protected void ddlExportRprts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileName="Test";
    string strDataFilePath = Server.MapPath("./AttachedFiles/") + "\\" + strFileName + ".xls";
    DownLoadFile(strDataFilePath, strFileName);
}


private void DownLoadFile(string strFilePath, string strFileName)
{
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFilePath))
   {
      Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + strFileName + ".xls");
      ddlExportRprts.SelectedValue = "0";
      Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath);
      Response.End();
   }
}
```

when ever I am selecting any option from drop down file is getting downloaded in selected format..no issues with that.

but after file is getting download and then I m clicking on any server side control like button, link button, check-box, radio-button any other drop down, this method 
"ddlExportRprts_SelectedIndexChanged()" is being called where as these controls has there on click events.

I am confuse why these method is being fired when I m not calling it.

I am stuck in this problem from long time, I hope some1 out there knew how to solve it..

cheers in advance.. 
: )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a file to the response, only the file is sent. The rest of the page doesn't get refreshed.

Due to this, the drop down selection event will be fired again at the server.

To avoid the `SelectedIndexChanged` event being triggered, you can reset the value of the dropdown to its original value before you submit the page using javascript.

Comment: I have already tried it
but was unsuccessful in it, when the control is coming to execute 'Response.End()' it is throwing 'ThreadAbortException' by which I m not ablt to reset the original value of the drop-down.

Comment: This is the modified code which I tried,

    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename =" + strFileName + ".xls");
    ddlExportRprts.SelectedValue = "0";
    Response.TransmitFile(strFilePath);
    Response.End();

Comment: I don't see the code you tried. `ThreadAbortException` is perfectly normal when you use `Response.End`

Comment: No, you cannot set it at the server side in C#. The changes you make there won't reach the browser cause you call `Response.End`. You have to do it using javascript, after you submit; probably using a javascript `setTimeOut`